# Springfox: Separated annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, springfox

I've created this interface:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
@Api(value = "Documents service", description = "This API has a CRUD for documents and related entities")
public interface IDocumentController {
   //... some methods
}
```

So, I've created an implementation:

```
public class DocumentController implements IDocumentController {
    //method implementations
}
```

Nevertheless, `v2/api-docs` gets me an empty api:

When I delete interface `IDocumentController` and I put all anotations on `DocumentController` class, swagger content is right.

I'd like to avoid to have an huge class with a lot of annotations and weak of code.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is related to this ticket. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/868. Currently it is not supported